# messageExchange.getTimestamp() maven overwriting value

Tags: maven, groovy, soapui

when using messageExchange.getTimestamp() directely friom soapui .

im getting the right values back. so the response time is around 50ms.

However, if i use maven to trigger the same project. then the time which is log for getTimestamp becomes 500ms.

so question is, is the "messageExchange.getTimestamp()" calcuiting the actual response time or the run time to trigger the request and get response ?

also, if the project contains more than one file. so 3 requests to be sent.

the first one takes 500ms
second one takes 50ms
and third takes 45ms

so the times for the second the third request are right. not the first.

how to fix this ?

logs below showing the time difference. keeping in mind its the same request. if this is run directly from soapui, issues isnt there. issue only comes up when we run this throguh maven.

```
        T E S T S
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Running com.test.app.AppTest
        Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec

        Results :

        Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- soapui-maven-plugin:5.2.1:test (soapUI4) @ projectNAme ---
        SoapUI 5.2.1 Maven2 TestCase Runner
        2017-02-27 10:44:57,239 [BuilderThread 0] INFO  com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner - Setting global property [enviroment] to [Enviroment]
        2017-02-27 10:44:57,239 [BuilderThread 0] INFO  com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner - Setting global property [projectname] to [projectNAme]
        10:44:57,939 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\test\soapui-settings.xml]
        10:45:02,071 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 2 ms
        10:45:02,071 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
        10:45:03,427 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/C:/automation/soapui-project.xml]
        10:45:03,437 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project [#resposnetimeAutomation]
        10:45:03,439 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running Project [#resposnetimeAutomation], runType = SEQUENTIAL
        10:45:05,637 INFO  [log] =============START=============
        10:45:05,669 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [Projecttest]
        10:45:05,677 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [setProperties]
        10:45:05,743 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [GetRequests]
        10:45:05,829 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [assignPropertyValues]
        10:45:06,078 INFO  [log] Assign prop about to send file name: tc_01_tst.xml
        10:45:06,202 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [TriggerRequest]
        10:45:06,818 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
        10:45:06,818 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /endpoint/test HTTP/1.0
        10:45:06,851 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        10:45:06,868 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
        10:45:06,912 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [verificationStep]
        10:45:08,222 INFO  [log] response Time in ms: ==================== 445
        10:45:08,222 INFO  [log] responsegetTimestamp Time in ms: ==================== 1488152706869
        10:45:08,222 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:08,222 INFO  [log] HTTP status code: 200
        10:45:08,223 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:09,262 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [triggerrequest]
        10:45:09,285 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
        10:45:09,285 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /endpoint/test HTTP/1.0
        10:45:09,312 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        10:45:09,312 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
        10:45:09,322 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [verificationStep]
        10:45:09,323 INFO  [log] response Time in ms: ==================== 31
        10:45:09,324 INFO  [log] responsegetTimestamp Time in ms: ==================== 1488152709313
        10:45:09,324 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:09,324 INFO  [log] HTTP status code: 200
        10:45:09,324 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:09,933 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [assignPropertyValues]
        10:45:09,933 INFO  [log] Assign prop about to send file name: tc2dass.xml
        10:45:09,978 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [triggerrequest]
        10:45:09,987 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
        10:45:09,987 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /endpoint/test HTTP/1.0
        10:45:10,008 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        10:45:10,009 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
        10:45:10,017 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [verificationStep]
        10:45:10,019 INFO  [log] response Time in ms: ==================== 25
        10:45:10,020 INFO  [log] responsegetTimestamp Time in ms: ==================== 1488152710009
        10:45:10,020 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:10,020 INFO  [log] HTTP status code: 200
        10:45:10,020 INFO  [log] ==================================================================================
        10:45:10,713 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Projecttest], time taken: 4908ms, status: FAILED
        10:45:10,723 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Project [#resposnetimeAutomation] finished with status [FAILED] in 7278ms
```

Comment: Can you show the test case structure? Are you running load test?

Comment: hi rao, no not load tests. its the same requests with different data every time. it takes maven much longer for the first test to run. then the following tests are fine. is there any settings in maven, POM, soapui that can fix this ?